# How can I compare a float to NaN if comparisons to NaN always return false?

Tags: c#

I have a float value set to NaN (seen in the Watch Window), but I can't figure out how to detect that in code:

```
if (fValue == float.NaN) // returns false even though fValue is NaN
{
}
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You want `float.IsNaN(...)`. Comparisons to `NaN` always return false, no matter what the value of the float is. It's one of the quirks of floating points.

That means you can do this:

```
if (f1 != f1) { // This conditional will be true if f1 is NaN.
```

In fact, that's exactly how IsNaN() works.

Comment: f1 != f1 triggers a warning "Comparison made to same variable;" so I'm just using float.IsNaN, however I really want to use f1 != f1 just to confuse people. :-)

Comment: This is giving me flash backs to Java.

Answer (score 38):

Try this:

```
if (float.IsNaN(fValue))
{
}
```

Answer (score 16):

In performance-critical code `float.IsNaN` could be too slow because it involves FPU. In that case you can use binary mask check (according to [IEEE 754 specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision)) as follow:

```
public static unsafe bool IsNaN (float f)
{
    int binary = *(int*)(&f);
    return ((binary & 0x7F800000) == 0x7F800000) && ((binary & 0x007FFFFF) != 0);
}
```

It is 5 times faster than `float.IsNaN`. I just wonder why Microsoft did not implement `IsNaN` in such way. If you'd prefer not using unsafe code you still can use union-like structure:

```
[StructLayout (LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct FloatUnion
{
    [FieldOffset (0)]
    public float value;

    [FieldOffset (0)]
    public int binary;
}

public static bool IsNaN (float f)
{
    FloatUnion union = new FloatUnion ();
    union.value = f;

    return ((union.binary & 0x7F800000) == 0x7F800000) && ((union.binary & 0x007FFFFF) != 0);
}
```

It's still 3 times faster than `IsNaN`.

Comment: "I just wonder why Microsoft did not implement IsNaN in such way." Because that code is platform-dependent and would break elsewhere.

Comment: Floating-point data structure is described in IEEE 754 and is platform-independent. Moreover, checks on infinity are implemented in .NET via binary comparisons e.g. `((*(((int*) &f)) & 0x7fffffff) == 0x7f800000)`.

Comment: The floating-point _data structure_ is platform-independent, but endianness isn't.

Comment: Is binary comparison really endian-dependent? Byte order in binary mask will be the same as in int value.

Anyway, if Microsoft decided to use such check on infinity, they could use the same way for NaN checks.

Comment: It seems NaN is rarely concerned in performance critical code. Why do you need it? It's generated by 0/0, in most cases it's an exception.

Comment: I've made this investigation when I faced a need to check a large array of floats on NaN's.

Comment: Note that inside WPF, Microsoft uses a similar technique for checking IsNaN on Doubles. The source is commented indicating that this is a perf optimization and that there's an internal work item to switch the framework over to the improved implementation. Here's the link: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Shared/MS/Internal/DoubleUtil.cs,303

Comment: This is now how double.IsNaN works: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,101

Answer (score 8):

```
if(float.isNaN(fValue))
{
}
```

Comment: This is a C# question. There is no such method `isNaN` on `Float` in C#; it's `IsNaN`, with a capital "I".

Answer (score 1):

```
if (fValue.CompareTo(float.NaN) == 0)
```

Note: I know, the thread is dead.